# .htaccess rewrite complete path w/ all files (no redirect)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite a directory to another directory. The file/link structure to all files (like css/js/images/GET vars etc.) have to keep intact.

My files currently are in **http://www.example.org/_directory1/output/index.php?site=site1**

The new path should be **http://www.example.org/newDir/index.php?site=site1**

In a nutshell /_directory1/output/ should changed to /newDir/.

Comment: I played a little around w/ **RewriteRule ^newDir/(.*)$ /var/www/theSite/_directory1/output/index.php?site=$1 [NC]** but that didnt affect the css and js files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule http://www.example.org/_directory1/output/$1 ^newDir/(.*)$ [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /newDir/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.org/newDir/$1
```

in your .htaccess in /_directory1/output/

The [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) documentation may help you further.